# Julia pmap: How to effectively send helper functions to other workers?

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

When using `pmap` function, an error would occur if the function is not defined on any of the worker processes. However, when the function calls other functions or using other functions inside another `.jl` file, to use `@everywhere` macro on every related functions is certainly not a good solution.

Is there a neat way to effectively send a function along with its helpers to all available workers?

Comment: Come on #parallel-processing folks — this is a perfectly fine question with a good answer.  Must we put it on hold?

Answer (score 3):

I do not think there is a macro that can be used with a function definition to send the definitions of all its helper functions to all the worker processes.

However, there are better ways to send all the functions you need than putting an `@everywhere` before each of them.

You can put all these functions in a file and `include` it everywhere with `@everywhere include("mynewfile.jl")`. If your functions use other functions inside another `.jl` file, put that `include` statement for the other file in `mynewfile.jl` as well. If you are using modules from the other file, put the `using` or `import` statements inside `mynewfile.jl`

In a similar way, instead of a file, you can use `@everywhere begin...end` block. Put all these functions, `using` or `import` statements, `include`s etc. into a `begin...end` block and put an `@everywhere` before the `begin`. This is especially useful if you are working with IJulia notebooks.

```
julia> @everywhere begin
           g(x) = x^2
           f(x) = g(x)*2
       end

julia> pmap(f, 1:5)
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
  2
  8
 18
 32
 50
```

You can also create modules/packages and just use a single `@eveywhere using MyNewModule`. If you are using modules outside a package, you should also include the definitions/file of that module everywhere.

You might find it useful to read [the relevant manual entry.](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/parallel-computing/#Code-Availability-and-Loading-Packages-1)